# Ввод в массив через клавиатуру c++

Tags: c++, массивы

Уважаемые программисты, возник такой вопрос: можно ли в c++ сделать ввод в массив численного типа(допустим int) заранее не сообщая компилятору сколько там будет элементов? Допустим ввожу я числа 12 423 111 2, потом делаю вывод массива и он мне выводит эти же числа? Как бы чтобы он сам понимал сколько там элементов сразу в момент ввода. Вроде как с векторами что-то такое можно делать или даже с обычным массивом с указателем.

Comment: Просто надо решить, как определять конец ввода. Что это значит? 10 секунд не вводить новое значение? Ввести слово "всё"? Как только вы решите, что является концом ввода — так сразу можно будет и писать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, например так, если вы нажмёте CTRL+D при завершении ввода:

```
    int x;
    std::vector<int> a;
    while(std::cin >> x) {
        a.push_back(x);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
```

Если считать, что переносом строки заканчивается массив, то вот так:

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    std::vector<int> a;
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    ss << s;
    while(ss >> x) {
        a.push_back(x);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: А почему именно CTRL + D ?

Comment: CTRL+D посылает в std::cin  EOF(end of file), в таком случае (std::cin >> x) преобразуется к false и цикл завершится

Comment: Понял спасибо! А есть ли еще какие-то способы, но без ввода чего-то стороннего?

Comment: Без ввода чего-либо никак не получится, вам в любом случае нужно знать где закончился ввод массива. Можно считать, что массив заканчивается переносом строки. Не знаю считается это чем-то постронним или нет.

Comment: Ctrl-D — это Linux, в Windows, например, Ctrl-Z...